# Converting From Graql To Java API

Tags: java, parsing, vaticle-typeql, vaticle-typedb

I have started trying to use the java api to automate some work. Is there a simple way to convert graql queries which I can run on the visualiser and shell into ones I can use with the java api.

For example the query:

```
match $x isa product
```

I see that I can write that as

```
match(var("x").isa("product"));
```

Is there no way to map the string format to the java format automatically?

I feel I am missing something simple.

Thanks,

Kieran.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `QueryBuilder`
https://grakn.ai/pages/documentation/developing-with-java/java-graql.html#query-parser

```
for (Concept x : qb.<MatchQuery>parse("match $x isa person;").get("x")) {
    System.out.println(x);
}

if (qb.<AskQuery>parse("match has name 'Bob' isa person; ask;").execute()) 
{
  System.out.println("There is someone called Bob!");
}

qb.parse("insert isa person, has firstname 'Alice';").execute();

qb.parse("match $x isa person; delete $x;").execute();
```